# How to get the latest date from a collection of DateTime?

Tags: datetime, d

I have got array of with type DateTime `DateTime [] dts;`
How I can get the latest date from it?

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for sorting. And using `minPos` might not be the most convenient way to get the largest value, as it returns a range

You could just use `reduce` with `max` as a predicate. This approach will work with any range or comparable elements, not just `DateTime`

```
import std.datetime;
import std.algorithm;
import std.stdio;

void main(){
    DateTime[] times;   // array of DateTimes filled with dummy data
    foreach (i; 0 .. 5) {
        times ~= DateTime() + dur!"seconds"(2 * i);
    }

    auto t = times.reduce!max;

    writefln("All Times: %s", times);
    writefln("Most Recent Time: %s", t);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[minPos](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html#.minPos) is another `std.algorithm` option.

`auto latestDateTime = dts.minPos!((a,b) => a > b).front`;

Don't let the name `minPos` decieve you, it can be used to find the max too, just by telling it to use a different comparison as I did above (if you wanted the earliest date, `dts.minpos.front` would be enough).
Like most D algorithms, `minPos` returns a range, so `front` is needed to actually grab the element.

`minPos` should do less work than `sort`, plus it avoids the issue that `sort` mutates the original array.

Comment: `sort` is an eager algorithm, it will sort data in-place, no lazy evaluation is involved

Answer (score 1):

This is a stupid example, but does the job:

```
import std.datetime;
import std.algorithm;
import std.stdio;
import core.thread;
void main(){
    DateTime[] times;   // array of DateTimes filled with dummy data
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        times ~= DateTime() + dur!"seconds"(2 * i);
    }

    // This is the important line to take away from this. 
    // It uses std.algorithm.sort to sort the array in ascending order.
    // .front then takes the first item from the result
    auto t = times.sort!((a,b) => a > b).front;

    writefln("All Times: %s", times);
    writefln("Most Recent Time: %s", t);
}
```

Comment: `sort` is destructive algorithm - it sorts in-place, also this will do more work then is actually required to get the value

Comment: Yep, you're right. Your answer with reduce!max is much better!